# new Thread() and Threadpool?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, task-parallel-library

Why does a Thread *(which I set  `IsBackgroundthread` to `True`)* is not running with the threadpool Threads ?

```
/*1*/   volatile bool r = false;
/*2*/   var g= new Thread(() => r=Thread.CurrentThread.IsThreadPoolThread );
/*3*/   g.IsBackground = true;
/*4*/   g.Start();
/*5*/   g.Join();
/*6*/   Console.WriteLine(r); //false
```

While this code (obviously) does run at a threadpool thread ?

```
 Task.Factory.StartNew(()=>Console.Write(Thread.CurrentThread.IsThreadPoolThread)); //true
 Console.ReadLine();
```

*p.s.
(I know that Task are (by default)run at a background threads and they run in a threadpool , but my question is about a similar situation where I set a thread to run at background).)*

Comment: “I know that Task are always background threads” Not always, if you set a `TaskScheduler`, the `Task` will run wherever you want.

Comment: @svick yes indeed.  (I mean to default ) Ill rephrase.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The IsBackground property does not do what you think it does.  It is merely a flag that tells the CLR whether it is okay to abort the thread when the non-background threads complete, including the main thread of the program.  If it is *false*, the default value, then the CLR won't interfere with the thread, allowing it to complete.  Setting it to *true* invokes the equivalent of Thread.Abort(), minus the ability for the thread to do anything about it or be notified about it.  A rude abort.

The thread created by the Thread class is never pooled, unless some kind of custom CLR host is used which is very rare.  Common ways to create a threadpool thread are ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem,() BackgroundWorker, a delegate's BeginInvoke() method and the Task class.

Comment: A background thread is ended when all forground threads end, not when the main thread ends.  Newly spawned forground threads will keep background threads alive.

Answer (score 7):

The ThreadPool is a pool of *dedicated* threads managed by the runtime.

User-created background threads are not part of the threadpool.

In other words, all thread-pool threads are background threads, but not all background threads are thread-pool threads.

Comment: why ?what's the difference between the Task to my Backgroundthread ? ( except for continuity etc...)